# Are side lengths enough to find the ratio of the diagonals of a quadrilateral?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Is it possible to find the ratio of two diagonals of a quadrilateral when the length of all sides are given??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't know some of the angles, then no. This is not to difficult to see by drawing some pictures (or even better, bending something like a straw into the shape of a quadrilateral, and then deforming it). Keeping all the lengths of the sides fixed, you can vary the angles to produce some fairly extreme shapes - in particular, you can draw lots of quadrilaterals with the same four side lengths, but wildly different diagonal lengths.

**Note:** The question has significantly changed in an edit, to ask about the ratio of the diagonals, rather than the lengths. However, the same answer applies (imagine taking a square, where the two diagonals have equal length, and squashing two opposite corners together without changing the side lengths, to get a rhombus, where the diagonals are different).